# Twitter bootstrap column layout issue

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I Have the following code below , the problem i am having is that I noticed no matter what I do , I can't seem to have the right side of the extra  real-state  reduced as the right side seems to be having lots of extra spaces in step1 and step2.

I was trying to have it balanced for desktop, tablet and mobile.

Can some one show me how to fix this.

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x3es0pfs/33/)

My code below

HTML

```
<div class="container claim-c">

  <div class="row claimBordercolor">


    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-3 claim-divider">

      <h2 class="steps "> <span class="steppos">STEP</span> <span class='circle pull-right'>1</span></h2>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm10 col-md-9">
      <h4 class="claim-hdr" style="color:#fff">CURRENT </h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-4 col-md-4 ">

          <label class="control-label required" for="name">SOME SOME Number <i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
          <h2><span class="label label-warning orPos">OR</span></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-4  col-md-4">

          <label class="control-label " for="name"> Some/test s&nbsp;Lotus &nbsp;Number</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
  <!-- end of row -->


  <div class="row claimBordercolor">

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-3 claim-divider2">
      <h2 class="steps "> <span class="steppos">STEP</span>  <span class='circle pull-right'>2</span></h2>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-md-9">
      <h4 class="claim-hdr" style="color:#fff"> LoremIpsumorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLoremipsum lorem ipsum.</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          <label class="control-label " for="name">Date of Birth(MM/DD/YYYY)</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
          <label class="control-label " for="name"> Type</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8  col-sm-2 col-md-1">
          <h2><span class="label label-warning orPos">OR</span></h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4  col-md-4">
          <label class="control-label " for="name"> Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />

          <label class="control-label " for="name">ZIP </label>
          <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of row -->





</div>
```

CSS

```
       .circle {
     position: relative;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 47px;
     color: #000;
     border-radius: 50%;
     border: 2px solid #fff;
     z-index: 999999;
   }

   .circle:after {
     position: absolute;
     content: '';
     top: 4px;
     left: 4px;
     height: calc(100% - 8px);
     width: calc(100% - 8px);
     border-radius: inherit;
     background: #fff;
     z-index: -1;
   }

   .circle.white:after {
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     border: 4px solid #000
   }

   .circle.image:after {
     background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/4);
   }

   .claim-c {
     border: 2px solid #ccc;
     background-color: #30A759;
     margin-top: 20px;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }

   .claim-c label {
     color: #fff !important;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     padding-top: 15px;
   }

   .claim-divider {
     border-right: 14px solid #fff;
     height: 190px;
     margin-top: 9px;
     margin-bottom: 9px;
   }

   .claim-divider2 {
     border-right: 14px solid #fff;
     height: 232px;
     margin-top: 9px;
     margin-bottom: 9px;
   }

   .claimBordercolor {
     /*  border:10px solid #FFCB00; */
     border: 10px solid rgba(12, 64, 28, 0.91);
   }

   .claim-hdr {
     width: 81%;
     color: #fff;
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }

   .margin-right20 {
     margin-right: 20px;
   }

   .steppos {
     color: #fff;
     position: relative;
     top: 7px;
     font-weight: bold;
   }

   .orPos {
     padding-right: 10px;
   }

   @media only screen and (max-width: 490px) {
     body {
       background-color: red;
     }
     .claim-divider {
       border-right: 14px solid #fff;
       height: 330px;
       margin-top: 9px;
       margin-bottom: 9px;
     }
     .claim-divider2 {
       border-right: 14px solid #fff;
       height: 582px;
       margin-top: 9px;
       margin-bottom: 9px;
     }
     .steppos {
       color: #fff;
       position: relative;
       top: -8px;
       font-weight: bold;
     }
     @media only screen and ( min-width:750px) {
       body {
         background-color: blue;
       }
       .claim-divider {
         border-right: 14px solid #fff;
         height: 330px;
         margin-top: 9px;
         margin-bottom: 9px;
       }
       .claim-divider2 {
         border-right: 14px solid #fff;
         height: 582px;
         margin-top: 9px;
         margin-bottom: 9px;
       }
       .steppos {
         color: #fff;
         position: relative;
         top: -8px;
         font-weight: bold;
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- you have a typo `.col-sm10`, should be, `.col-sm-10`
- in one of your rows you have a total of a 10 cols. when the maximum in bootstrap is 12, so instead of

`.col-sm-4` +  `.col-sm-2` +  `.col-sm-4` ( total = 10)

you can have:

`.col-sm-5` +  `.col-sm-2` +  `.col-sm-5` ( total = 12)

Same thing applies to `md` classes

- About `xs` class when you have `.col-xs-9` you should have `.col-xs-12`

### Snippet

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 47px;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  z-index: 999999;
}
.circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  height: calc(100% - 8px);
  width: calc(100% - 8px);
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
}
.circle.white:after {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: 4px solid #000
}
.circle.image:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/4);
}
.claim-c {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #30A759;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.claim-c label {
  color: #fff !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.claim-divider {
  border-right: 14px solid #fff;
  height: 190px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.claim-divider2 {
  border-right: 14px solid #fff;
  height: 232px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.claimBordercolor {
  /*  border:10px solid #FFCB00; */
  border: 10px solid rgba(12, 64, 28, 0.91);
}
.claim-hdr {
  width: 81%;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.margin-right20 {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.steppos {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.orPos {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 490px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .claim-divider {
    border-right: 14px solid #fff;
    height: 330px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
  }
  .claim-divider2 {
    border-right: 14px solid #fff;
    height: 582px;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
  }
  .steppos {
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    body {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .claim-divider {
      border-right: 14px solid #fff;
      height: 330px;
      margin-top: 9px;
      margin-bottom: 9px;
    }
    .claim-divider2 {
      border-right: 14px solid #fff;
      height: 582px;
      margin-top: 9px;
      margin-bottom: 9px;
    }
    .steppos {
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      top: -8px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container claim-c">
  <div class="row claimBordercolor">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-3 claim-divider">
      <h2 class="steps"> <span class="steppos">STEP</span> <span class="circle pull-right">1</span></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-md-9">
      <h4 style="color:#fff" class="claim-hdr">CURRENT </h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
          <label for="name" class="control-label required">SOME SOME Number <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>
          </label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" vk_1d97d="subscribed">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
          <h2><span class="label label-warning orPos">OR</span></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5  col-md-5">
          <label for="name" class="control-label ">Some/test s&nbsp;Lotus &nbsp;Number</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" vk_1d97d="subscribed">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="row claimBordercolor">
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2 col-md-3 claim-divider2">
        <h2 class="steps "> <span class="steppos">STEP</span>  <span class='circle pull-right'>2</span></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-10 col-md-9">
        <h4 class="claim-hdr" style="color:#fff"> LoremIpsumorem Ipsum Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLoremipsum lorem ipsum.</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
            <label class="control-label " for="name">Date of Birth(MM/DD/YYYY)</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
            <label class="control-label " for="name"> Type</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-2 col-md-2">
            <h2><span class="label label-warning orPos">OR</span></h2>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5  col-md-5">
            <label class="control-label " for="name"> Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />

            <label class="control-label " for="name">ZIP </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of row -->





  </div>

  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `col-md-4` to `col-md-6`.

```
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-4 col-md-6 ">
```

Also you have a few instances of `colsm` without the hyphen in between.

http://codepen.io/ruchiccio/pen/KzbBvB

Comment: i wanted them look  balanced in both side  so that there is no extra real estate on either side. the one that your showed one text box  looks larger and other side smaller  https://jsfiddle.net/x3es0pfs/33/

Comment: Sorry I just figured you would see the changes on the first one and do the rest yourself. You also specifically asked about the extra space on the right, not on the left.